# Is there a way to detect if a page is beeing published?

Tags: development, publishing-page, check-in, pages

following situation:

A user is editing a page in the Pages Library (PublishingFeature). The list settings are requiring a checkout to edit a document. Now he edit's a lot of things on this page, and because it's a WYSIWYG thing the current data is cached. What I need to do now is, to recognize when he checks in or saves the page and push the cached data to sharepoint.

P.S.
Were talking about SharePoint 2010.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way I'm using now:

[How to detect if and which ribbon button was pressed (SharePoint 2010)](http://www.just-a-programmer.com/uncategorized/sharepoint2010-how-to-detect-if-and-which-ribbon-button-was-pressed-during-postback.html)

Answer (score 0):

An alert on the library will inform you any changes.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom ItemCheckIn event receiver where you can do whatever control that you want.

If you want more information take a look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spitemeventreceiver.itemcheckedin.aspx